# Valid rearrangements of infinite series -- where is the bijection when you split up a series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, permutations

Suppose that you have a sequence of non-negative real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$.  I know that the value of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is unchanged if you permute the indices.

However, it's unclear to me whether this implies that, for instance, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$.  What permutation is being used here?  It seems like the idea behind this is not so much a permutation as it is "summing the evens first" and then the odds.  But it's not a permutation of $\Bbb N$ to map each number to the evens ... and then later map them to the odds.

Clearly what's going on here is

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{2k-1}+a_{2k}) $$

and I'm pretty sure an $\varepsilon,\delta$ argument would prove this equation true.

---

The question: But it's not really an instance of permutation is it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It isn't clear to me if your question is about the definition of "permutation" in this setting, or if you want an epsilon-delta proof that rearrangements of non-negative convergent series also converge? Or are you asking for both things in one question?

Comment: @AdamRubinson The question is whether there exists a permutation $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{2k-1}+a_{2k})$ is the same as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{f(n)}$.  Effectively the question is: is the principle of rearrangement of non-negative terms (i.e. the equality of series up to a permutation of the indices) sufficient to prove that a series can also be partitioned.  So it's not about what a partition is, nor requesting an $\varepsilon,N$ proof, but asking whether one fact is sufficient to prove another.

Comment: I think it is clear that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{2k-1}+a_{2k}) $ is a permutation of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, but it is not so clear if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$ is a permutation of  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ - I think this will depend on your definition of "permutation".

Comment: @AdamRubinson Fair point, although actually I think $a_{2k-1}+a_{2k}$ just has different terms than $a_n$.  So yes, that may depend on what you mean by a permutation--although I would think that it's pretty well agreed that a permutation just is a bijection.  But I take the point that there is also a significant move going on when distributing the sum.

Comment: We may consider $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$$ as a particular summation method for a double sequence $((a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty},(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty})$, or equivalently, a function indexed by $\mathbb{N}\times\{1,2\}$. Then we may regard the equality $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{2k}$$ as a consequence of the correspondence $$ (a_1,a_2,\dots)\quad\leftrightarrow\quad((a_1,a_3,\dots),(a_2,a_4,\dots))$$ that arise from the bijection $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to view this is that if all terms of a series are **nonnegative** then the sum can be defined as follows:
$$
\sum_{n\,\in\,I} a_n = \sup \left\{ \sum_{n\,\in\,I_0} : I_0 \subseteq I,\, I_0 \text{ is finite} \right\}.
$$
Then the task remains to show that this is equal to the sums defined by limits of partial sums in the various rearrangements-that-are-not-permutations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the value of the series $∑^∞_{n=1}a_n$ is unchanged if you permute the indices.

Wrong. Google "Riemann rearrangement theorem". What you say is only true if the series converges absolutely.

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$

Consider the partial sums up to $2N$ on the RHS (if the general term at least goes to zero, it isn't too hard to argue that the odd case is the same). This is true for all series(absolute and conditional convergence) for which both the summations on the RHS exist. Otherwise, we can say nothing.

EDIT: The theorem you state is true if $a_n$ are non negative(because the convergence must be absolute), sorry about that. Also of course in this case, both the series on the RHS exist by the comparison test. To show the summations are equal, we don't need to concern ourselves with series anymore, we just need to know $\lim(a_n+b_n)=\lim a_n+\lim b_n$ when both exist individually.

Comment: It was an assumption that the terms of the series are non-negative.  So if it converges it converges absolutely.  If it doesn't converge, then no rearrangement would make it converge.  By the way, softening the tone could ... be a little helpful.

Comment: @Addem Sorry about that. This is not a question of series once you know they converge absolutely. You are correct that you are not permuting the order really, one could say you are summing all the odds first, then the evens, but this isn't formal. Permuting the order is not the only way we can manipulate the series(/sequence).

Comment: Well ... clearly it's a question of series.  It's just a matter of, is it a permutation or is it handled differently.  Obviously there are other ways to handle series ... and that's why I'm asking.  Because I've seen in some other places, people explain this move as a rearrangement.  And it kind of looks like a rearrangement, but after some thought, it began do doubt that this is fully correct.  So I just wanted to be clear that it's really not, and that it is supposed to be handled differently.

Comment: @Addem This is not a question of series if you don't force it to be one, you are just showing $\lim(a_n+b_n)=\lim a_n + \lim b_n$, which I am sure you are familiar with and is much simpler than any proof about rearrangement. But the answer to your question is no, it is not a permutation.

Comment: So ... any question about series is never a question about series because you can always interpret a series as a limit of partial sums ... thanks.

Comment: @Addem No. Rearrangement is fundamentally a property of series. I understand that you mean to hold a grudge against me, but hopefully you have convinced yourself of the math.

Answer (score 0):

A note about this question which, if I had known this when I asked the question, would have allowed me to research the question better: Tonelli's theorem (or the Tonelli-Fubini theorem) would resolve this question easily.  So anyone interested in this can search for proofs of Tonelli's theorem.